# How to break down 5 minute rainfall recording into average in every minute

Tags: python, pandas

So this is how my dataframe looks:
[the first 20 rows of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkJfF.png)

As you can see, I have managed to create timestamp every 1 minute and set it to index. The thing is that the station only records rainfall every 5 minute. For example, the recording at '2019-01-01 00:05:00' represents the total amount of rainfall in the past five minutes and that's why i don't have readings from 00:01:00 to 00:04:00.

Now I want to replace all the 'nan' value with the recording every 5 mins divided by 5.

so if the reading at 00:05:00 is 5, I want to get something like:

```
                       year     month      day      hour     minute     sec      reading
2019-01-01 00:01:00     2019       1         1         0        1          0         1
2019-01-01 00:02:00     2019       1         1         0        2          0         1
2019-01-01 00:03:00     2019       1         1         0        3          0         1    
2019-01-01 00:04:00     2019       1         1         0        4          0         1
2019-01-01 00:05:00     2019       1         1         0        5          0         1
```

I think I can figure out how to fill in the year, month, day, hour, minute, sec on my own. I just need the readings. And note that the station's recording every 5 mins might also have missing data. Let's say there is supposed to be reading at 2019-01-01 23:55:00 but it did not record, so in the dataframe it is 'nan'. In this case I want the past five mins to all be 'nan'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haved a look here, does this work for you ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

Comment: if the value is 5 and you want the recording divided by 2 why is the reading 1?

Comment: wait im sorry i want it to be divided by 5

Comment: but which method should I use

Comment: I think to get the behavior you describe, use the pad method and then divide everything by 5. However, you may find a different interpolation method makes more sense for your data

Comment: I have tried the pad fill and divide by 5 method i think it's actually working! Thank you!